# How to implement attributes to an object/sprite in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Yu-Gi-Oh! card game with Pygame that works as a very simplified version of the video game versions (i.e. monster cards only, and they can only attack, thus for now they should only have attack points as attributes), just to try to gain some experience as an aspiring programmer by developing a simple game/project that seems interesting to me.

But now i'm struggling to implement the cards' atk points as attributes for the battle system, since each card is represented by a pygame sprite taken from a list of sprites from the very same class, instead of each card being its own instance of its own class for allowing proper attribute implementation. I'm really stuck on this, so would really really appreciate any solutions. I thought about implementing each card on its own class as just metioned, but since i wouldn't be able to know which cards have already been drawn at a given moment, i don't see how i would be able to properly filter the available cards to be drawn from the deck (the list named self.deck at card.py) at a given moment through the card list without repeating some of them that should be unavailable.

I tried my best right now to make my issue as clear as possible, so any suggestions to improve the clarity of my quesion is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

These are the relevant parts of code from the project:

From the main game file (card_game.py)

```
import sys

import pygame

from card import Card
from card import EnemyCards
from board import Board
from life_points import LifePoints
from deck import Deck
from deck import CPUDeck
from settings import Settings

import random, os

class CardGame:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Innitialize the game and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Card Game")
 
        self.lp = LifePoints(self)

        self.cards = Card(self)

        self.card_1_rect = self.cards.rect_1
        self.card_2_rect = self.cards.rect_2
        self.card_3_rect = self.cards.rect_3
        self.card_4_rect = self.cards.rect_4
        self.card_5_rect = self.cards.rect_5

        self.cpu_cards = EnemyCards(self)
        self.cpu_card_1_rect = self.cpu_cards.rect_1
        self.cpu_card_2_rect = self.cpu_cards.rect_2
        self.cpu_card_3_rect = self.cpu_cards.rect_3
        self.cpu_card_4_rect = self.cpu_cards.rect_4
        self.cpu_card_5_rect = self.cpu_cards.rect_5

        self.board = Board(self)

        self.deck = Deck(self)
        self.deck.position_deck()
        self.cpu_deck = CPUDeck(self)
        self.cpu_deck.position_deck()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                if self.player_turn == True: 
                    self._check_card_clicked(mouse_pos)
                else:
                    self._check_cpu_card_clicked(mouse_pos)

                if self.deck.deck_image_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    self.cards.draw_card()
                elif self.cpu_deck.deck_image_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    self.cpu_cards.draw_card()

    def _check_card_clicked(self, mouse_pos):
        """Checks if the player clicked on the card and if so, puts it on the board."""
        card_1_clicked = self.card_1_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        card_2_clicked = self.card_2_rect.collidepoint(mous e_pos)
        card_3_clicked = self.card_3_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        card_4_clicked = self.card_4_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        card_5_clicked = self.card_5_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)

        if card_1_clicked:
            self.card_1_rect.center = (419, 594)
        elif card_2_clicked:
            self.card_2_rect.center = (563, 585)
        elif card_3_clicked:
            self.card_3_rect.center = (715, 593)
        elif card_4_clicked:
            self.card_4_rect.center = (862, 591)
        elif card_5_clicked:
            self.card_5_rect.center = (1020, 593)

        self.battle_phase()

    def _check_cpu_card_clicked(self):
        """Selects an enemy card randomly and puts it on the field."""
        cpu_card_1_clicked = self.cpu_card_1_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        cpu_card_2_clicked = self.cpu_card_2_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        cpu_card_3_clicked = self.cpu_card_3_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        cpu_card_4_clicked = self.cpu_card_4_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        cpu_card_5_clicked = self.cpu_card_5_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)

        if cpu_card_1_clicked:
            # Places the CPU's first card on hand on the board's first spot
            # if there's no other card there already.
            self.cpu_card_1_rect.center = (419, 442)
        elif cpu-card_2_clicked:
            self.cpu_card_2_rect.center = (570, 444)
        elif cpu_card_3_clicked:
            self.cpu_card_3_rect.center = (712, 449)
        elif cpu_card_4_clicked:
            self.cpu_card_4_rect.center = (860, 441)
        elif cpu_card_5_clicked:
            self.cpu_card_5_rect.center = (1018, 446)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Updates images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.board.blitme()
        self.deck.blitme() 
        self.cpu_deck.blitme()
        self.cards.blitme_1()
        self.cards.blitme_2()
        self.cards.blitme_3()
        self.cards.blitme_4()
        self.cards.blitme_5()
        self.cpu_cards.blitme_1()
        self.cpu_cards.blitme_2()
        self.cpu_cards.blitme_3()
        self.cpu_cards.blitme_4()
        self.cpu_cards.blitme_5()

        if hasattr(self.cards, 'drawn_card_6'):
            self.cards.blitme_6()
            if self.cards.rect_6.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                self.cards.blitme_hover_6()

        if hasattr(self.cpu_cards, 'drawn_card_6'):
            self.cpu_cards.blitme_6()
            if self.cpu_cards.rect_6.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                self.cpu_cards.blitme_hover_6()

        if self.cards.rect_1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_1()

        if self.cards.rect_2.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_ pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_2()
            
        if self.cards.rect_3.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_3()

        if self.cards.rect_4.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_4()

        if self.cards.rect_5.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_5()

        if self.cpu_cards.rect_1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cpu_cards.blitme_hover_1()
        elif self.cpu_cards.rect_2.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cpu_cards.blitme_hover_2()
        elif self.cpu_cards.rect_3.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cpu_cards.blitme_hover_3()
        elif self.cpu_cards.rect_4.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cards.blitme_hover_4()
        elif self.cpu_cards.rect_5.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.cpu_cards.blitme_hover_5()

        # Draw Life Points information.
        self.lp.show_life_points()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    cg = CardGame()
    cg.run_game()
```

and these are the relevant parts of the card.py file, where cards' functionalities are present:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from settings import Settings

import random, os


class Card(Sprite):
    """A class to manage a card."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize a card and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.deck = [
        "starter_deck/abyss_flower.bmp", 
        "starter_deck/acid_crawler.bmp", 
        "starter_deck/acrobat_monkey.bmp",
        "starter_deck/akakieisu.bmp",
        "starter_deck/alinsection.bmp",
        "starter_deck/alligators_sword.bmp",
        "starter_deck/ancient_brain.bmp",
        "starter_deck/ancient_elf.bmp",
        "starter_deck/ancient_jar.bmp",
        "starter_deck/bickuribox.bmp",
        "starter_deck/celtic_guardian.bmp",
        "starter_deck/curse_of_dragon.bmp",
        "starter_deck/gemini_elf.bmp",
        "starter_deck/la_jinn.bmp",
        "starter_deck/skull_knight.bmp"
        ]

        # Load the cards' images and get their rects.
        self.cards = [pygame.image.load(c) for c in self.deck]

        self.drawn_card_1 = random.choice(self.cards)
        self.drawn_card_2 = random.choice(self.cards)

        # This whole while loop section is intended to make sure that we get
        # 5 distinct cards from one another. 
        while self.drawn_card_1 == self.drawn_card_2:
            self.drawn_card_2 = random.choice(self.cards)

        self.drawn_card_3 = random.choice(self.cards)

        while (self.drawn_card_1 == self.drawn_card_3 
                or self.drawn_card_2 == self.drawn_card_3):
            self.drawn_card_3 = random.choice(self.cards)

        self.drawn_card_4 = random.choice(self.cards)

        while (self.drawn_card_1 == self.drawn_card_4
                or self.drawn_card_2 == self.drawn_card_4
                or self.drawn_card_3 == self.drawn_card_4):
            self.drawn_card_4 = random.choice(self.cards)

        self.drawn_card_5 = random.choice(self.cards)

        while (self.drawn_card_1 == self.drawn_card_5
                or self.drawn_card_2 == self.drawn_card_5
                or self.drawn_card_3 == self.drawn_card_5
                or self.drawn_card_4 == self.drawn_card_5):
            self.drawn_card_5 = random.choice(self.cards)

        

class EnemyCards(Sprite):
    """A class to manage the CPU's cards."""
    ...
```

P.S.: The term 'hover' present in the names of some variables and methods refers to displaying a bigger image of the card while hovering over them with the cursor, but that's not important i guess.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

to start off, it's unclear exactly what the problem is here so it is hard to make an answer but I'll give my best guess:

### Potential Answer

You have the main card class with all the general code for every card, why don't you create a new class for every card and [inherent](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/inheriting-one-class-another/) the base card class? This would mean you could still find common attributes across all cards while still having separate instances for each card.

If your problem is trying to manage which cards have been drawn and which cards remain in the deck, I would suggest storing some basic information about each card (inc which cards are drawn or not) in a dict (or a dict of dicts if you want to store more than just drawn status)

### General Suggestions

When you are writing code, it is really important for a multitude of factors to try and implement the principals of [DRY](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/DRY-principle) (Don't Repeat Yourself), you have a lot of code where you effectively iterate over cards 1-5 all on separate lines - maybe look at doing that in a for loop?

This would also be aided by implementing the use of lists or dicts to store data, as it would mean you can dynamically update all of the cards attributes in loops.

Here's an example from your code where it would be beneficial to store your data in a list

```py
    cpu_cards_rects = {1: rect_1, 2: rect_2, 3: rect_3, 4: rect_4, 5: rect_5}

    def _check_cpu_card_clicked(self):
        """Selects an enemy card randomly and puts it on the field."""
        centerPoints = {1: (419, 442), 2: (570, 444), 3: (712, 449), 4: (860, 441), 5: (1018, 446)}
        for card in centerPoints:
            collidePoint = self.cpu_card_rects[card].collidepoint(mouse_pos)
            if collidePoint:
                self.cpu_card_rects[card].center = centerPoints[card]
```

You could (and should) go one step further and store *all* card information in a single dict that each function can access & loop over.

### StackOverflow question suggestions

Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help guide questions in the future, and is made by SO to help people solve your problem! Here are a couple of my critiques:

Your question is really hard to understand as you provide a significant amount of information that doesn't relate to the problem at all. When asking questions on Stack Overflow, you want to try and provide the least amount of code/information possible to get your problem across.

In your description of the problem, for me at least, the most important piece of information was this:

> sprite taken from a list of sprites from the very same class, instead
> of each card being its own instance each card being its own instance
> of its own class for allowing proper attribute implementation

But instead of focusing on this and elaborating exactly what your problem was, you spent the rest of the question telling us about the game and your code. In the future, you want to try and make that the highlight :)

### Takeaways

All in all, good job asking for help (especially here), it can be very daunting so I'm glad you took the time. Try implementing the code practises I've outlined as well as the advice for asking questions in the future.

If the potential answer to your problem is not what you are after, leave a comment with more info abt what you are struggling with and I'll give it a shot

Comment: Hey man, i really appreciate your input. I will try to come up with some solution based off your answer, and if i get stuck again i'll write back here and will try to make the issue clerarer and to the point then. Thanks!